# I want to call a C# delegate from C++ unmanaged code. A parameterless delegate works fine , but a delegate with parameters crashed my program

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

The Following is code of a function from a unmanged dll. It takes in a function pointer as argument and simply returns value returned by the called function.

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) int  _stdcall callDelegate(int (*pt2Func)());
extern __declspec(dllexport) int  _stdcall callDelegate(int (*pt2Func)())
{
    int r = pt2Func();
    return r;
}
```

In managed C# code I call the umanged function above with a delegate.

```
  unsafe public delegate int mydelegate( );

    unsafe public int delFunc()
    {
             return 12;
    }

    mydelegate d = new mydelegate(delFunc);
    int re = callDelegate(d);
   [DllImport("cmxConnect.dll")]
    private unsafe static extern int callDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] mydelegate d);
```

This all works great !! but if I want my function pointer/delegate to take arguments it crashed the program.
So if I modify the code as follows my program crashes.

Modified unmanaged c++ -

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) int  _stdcall callDelegate(int (*pt2Func)(int));
extern __declspec(dllexport) int  _stdcall callDelegate(int (*pt2Func)(int))
{
    int r = pt2Func(7);
    return r;
}
```

Modified C# code -

```
unsafe public delegate int mydelegate( int t);

        unsafe public int delFunc(int t)
        {
                 return 12;
        }

        mydelegate d = new mydelegate(delFunc);
        int re = callDelegate(d);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calling convention for the function pointer is wrong.  Make it look like this:

```
 int (__stdcall * pt2Func)(args...)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this should work:

C++ DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall doWork(int worktodo, int(__stdcall *callbackfunc)(int));
```

C# Code:

```
delegate int del (int work);    

[DllImport(@"mydll")]
private static extern void doWork(int worktodo, del callback); 

int callbackFunc(int arg) {...} 

...

del d = new del(callbackFunc);
doWork(1000, d);
```