# Calling C# callbacks from C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I want to start by saying, I'm not a fluent C# or C++ developer, so I sincerely apologize in advance if this question has been asked many times before.I've tried Googling and searching but I'm tripping over chairs in the dark. I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish the following:

I have a DLL that does some complicated processing of RGB data and Depth-image data, written in C++.

I have two classes in C# as follows:

```
class DataProvider {
    public char* getImageData() {
        //...
    }

    public char* getDepthData() {
         //...
    }
 }

 class DataReceiver {
     public void frameReceived(float arg1, float arg2) {
        //do something meaningful here after processing is finished
     }
 }
```

My intention is to register instances of both classes to a processing function in the C++ DLL, and have the C++ DLL call the frameReceived method within the DataReceiver class instance. I just don't know what/how to pass the class instances from C# to C++.

NOTE: Importing the DLL in C# and defining the access functions on the C# end really isn't the issue. The issue is how to handle the C# code in C++ land.

Comment: You may use COM interop or simply function pointers (as delegates in C#).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti If you can provide a working example pastebin, fiddle, or otherwise in a post I'll mark you as correct.

Comment: Just take a look to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374433/i-want-to-call-a-c-sharp-delegate-from-c-unmanaged-code-a-parameterless-deleg) here on SO for an example.

Comment: It's important to hold your delegate instance in private values, to avoid the garbage collector to collect them and C++ cause a GPF while calling the callback. I'd provide a sample, but my blog isn't acessible behind a firewall and stack overflow fights with me if I post my blog link :-(

Comment: @EricLemes could you use pastebin? dotnetfiddle.net ? ideone.com ?